# How to transfer screenshots from iPhone to OS X?

Tags: macos, ios

I dont' want it done automatically, I just want to get a bunch of screenshots from the phone to the Mac (OS X El Capitan). I plug in the phone but only iTunes starts up and I can't find any photos in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Connect your iPhone to your Mac via with the lightning cable
2. Open *Image Capture* app
3. Select your iPhone under on the left sidebar

You can now select all the screenshots taken on your iPhone and import to your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get it accomplished by using AirDrop between my iPhone and my Mac Mini by selecting either a single photo of a variety of photos or even an event of photos and selecting the Share button

Answer (score -1):

Select picture on iPhone -> Export icon (box with arrow pointing out) -> Scroll through options where to send (ex. email or google drive)

Comment: There's like 20 screenshots, and when I click the icon my Mac isn't on the list. I just wanted to copy the files.

Comment: Yep.. There are limits when selecting so many.  If your Mac is newer, you can Airdrop--super cool but only on latest Macs